# Богатырь и батыр

Tags: этимология

Правда ли, что русское слово "богатырь" происходит от тюркского (или монгольского?) "батыр"? Или это все-таки исконно русское слово?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такие вещи с матемематической точностью доказать обычно невозможно.
Но на "исконно русское" - уж никак не тянет, подходящей славянской основы нету. Это задорновская шутка. 
Версия происхождения от тюркского "батыр" (исходно, видимо, монголькое "баатар", проникшее и в тюркские) наиболее вероятна.

Comment: up..........

Comment: По поводу того, что подходящей славянской основы нет, не согласен. Есть и русское **богатый**, и ст.-слав., болг., сербохорв., словен. **богат**. Вставка (суффикс) *-ырь-* существует: пустой -> пустырь, вести -> поводырь, пузо -> пузырь, водлый (водяной) -> волдырь, снег -> *снѣгырь, пасти -> пастырь (возможно). В общем, имеются и производящая основа, и суффикс для гипотетического славянского происхождения слова "богатырь".

Comment: Русское "богатый" не имеет подходящей семантики.

Comment: Она, возможно, выветрилась, но была. Обратимся к Фасмеру:

*От *bogъ "бог" или *bogъ "достояние, доля" в *sъbožьje "хлеб в зерне", укр. збíжжя, польск. zboże "хлеб в зерне", раньше "богатство", чеш. zboží "состояние"; ср. еще убо́гий. Согласно В. Шульце (KZ 45, 190 = Kl. Schriften 469), образовано аналогично лат. fortunātus, т. е. **хранимый богами**.*

То есть *богатый* изначально — это тот, кто наделён чем-то особенным, хранимый богами и пр. Тогда "богатырь" — это тот, кому благоволят боги, кто наделён огромной силой и пр.

Comment: Поясните. Судя по всему, вы неправильно Фасмера читаете "хранимый богами" - это *убогий*, а совсем не богатый. Это первое. Второе. Я говорит о семантике, которая бы дала основания считать "богатырь" суффиксальным образованием по  вашему  образцу. Вы её не пояснили ни в каком варианте. Богатырь = богач это не вариант. Переносное значение получается, а в примерах у вас - все прямые.

Comment: Фасмер приводит версию Шульце, что слово *богатый* образовано подобно латинскому *fortunātus* (хранимый богами и, как следствие, удачливый, успешный, благополучный) от глагола *fortuno* (делать счастливым), а не *убогий*. Что касается семантики, то существительное *богатырь* могло означать носителя признака. Признаком в данном случае является не материальное богатство, а успешность или покровительство свыше. Похожий в семантическом отношении случай — это слово "удалец" (храбрец), родственное слову "удача" и восходящее к *дать*. Кстати, глагол φερω (phero) тоже значит "передать", "нести".

Comment: "Фасмер приводит версию Шульце"  - но это же не значит, что он с ней соглашается??? И вообще к чему это? Мой ответ касался возможности производства слова богатырь от праславянской основы, а бог - само по себе слово заимствованное, только на очень древней стадии.

Comment: Обычно Фасмер явно выражал своё несогласие, если оно имело место. Моё замечание тоже касалось возможности производства слова *богатырь* на славянской основе. Я считаю, что она была. Другое дело, как всё произошло на самом деле.

Comment: *Обычно Фасмер явно выражал своё несогласие, если оно имело место.* - обычно это соображение не является аргументом. Как версию Шульце - ради бога, рассматривайте. Но на Фасмера не перекладывайте.

Comment: Весь словарь Фасмера — это "соображения". Итак, существовали и корень, и суффикс для образования слова "богатырь" на праславянской основе. Как было на самом деле — это уже другой вопрос.

Comment: *Весь словарь Фасмера — это "соображения"* - ну и?

Comment: *Итак, существовали и корень, и суффикс для образования слова "богатырь" на праславянской основе.* - Неужели "итак" добавляет солидности очевидно ошибочному тезису?  Итак, не они **не** существовали. Ну хорошо, "богатый" вы объявили корнем. А суфикс-то какой и откуда взялся? "-атырь" - это что за незаконнорожденный суффикс?

Comment: Это в современном монгольском баатар, в традиционной писменности - багатур (ᠪᠠᠭᠠᠲᠦᠷ)

Answer (score 1):

Корни безусловно тюрко-монгольские.

*Батыр, боотур, баатар* и проч. в тюркском обозначает *"буйный", "забияка"*, *"храбрец"* - ближе по смыслу наверное к *драчливый*. Например, часто говорят по злую собаку - боотур/батыр.

Comment: А чем монгольское "баатар" хуже? Улан-Батор это, кстати, всего лишь Красный Богатырь. Сухебатор (деятель такой, если кто не знает) - топор-богатырь (или еще какая метла, запамятовал уже) и т.д. Вопрос в том, кто у кого заимствовал. Руссие с монголами общались очень давно... Татарами их по недоразумению назвали. А вот с начтоящими тюрками - это уже когда Казань брали...

Comment: В современном татарском батыр - именно богатырь, но кто от кого позаимствовал - не знаю. Есть еще похожее имя: 
 
> БАХАДИР, БАХАДУР
>    Богатырь, герой; обладающий огромной силой.

> Татарские, тюркские, мусульманские мужские имена. Словарь терминов..  

Этим же именем у нас называется магазин спортивных товаров. Про драчливость или буйство не слышала (наверное, этот оттенок смысла пропал)

Comment: @behemothus контакты русских с тюрками были гораздо раньше Казанских событий. Печенеги и половцы тюрки с ними контакты были еще во времена Киевской Руси - так что богатырь я думаю, был заимствован еще в домонгольское время.

Comment: Если печенегов держать за тюрков, то гуннов - за монголов.
Мы так до Адама дойдём. Надо ж все-таки смотреть, как слово могло попасть в язык, а не просто кто с кем пересекался на дорогах истории.

Comment: *Корни безусловно тюркские* -.Монгольские там корни. Слово "батыр" даже не во всех "тюркских" есть. Когда говорим о такой древности, нельзя быть настолько неаккуратным в терминах.

Comment: Соглашусь, что тюркские корни неоднозначны. Поправлю ответ.

Answer (score 0):

В "Слове" младшего брата Игоря зовут "буй-тур", канонически объясняя прозвище восходящим к "тур" с латинской основой "taurus" (бык). Но мне оно видится очень схожим с все тем же "богатырем" ("батыром")
Чисто в качестве предположения...

Comment: Да не было до моголо-татар на Руси батыров.

Comment: "Такие вещи с математической точностью доказать обычно невозможно"

Comment: Какие? Про Батыров? Это-то можно... Влияние монголов было минимальным, если вообще было. Не путать с тюрками, хотя и с ними контакты были весьма ограниченными. Но слово-то монгольское, к татарам волжским через них попало.

Comment: А вот про буй-тура это да. Бог знает, что там можно доказать на основании какой-то там легенды и "видится"...

Comment: Прошу прощения за свой корявый слог, но я не в контрдансе с вами, а как раз наоборот. Поясню: 1 - каноническая (общепринятая литературоведами) трактовка относит прозвище "буй-тур" к латинской основе "таурус" (бык); 2 - я же вижу в этом слове как раз не латинские, а именно монгольские корни слова с основой б-т-р, т.е. монгольский "батыр" (богатырь). Видимо, вы не заметили антитезы "но" между 1-й и 2-1 фразой

Answer (score 0):

А  монгольская  версия  чем  плоха ?  Контакты  древнерусской  и  монгольской  элит  с  тринадцатого  века  были ?  Были.  Монгольскую  лексику  использовать  могли.  Могли.  Иноязычная  лексика  —  дело  обычное.  В  монгольском  "баатар"  есть  не  свойственное  русской  речи  зияние —  появляется  протетический  Г  или  Х,  или  среднее  между  ними.  А  последний  слог  претерпевает  изменения  по  тюркской  модели  или  также  как  тюркской,  или  просто  по  удобству  произношения.

Answer (score 0):

Обратите внимание, что из славянских языков слово богатырь есть только в русском языке. Даже на белорусском богатырь - волат. Когда-то немецкие историки при дворе русских самодержавцев натравили русских против всего тюркского. С тех пор и продолжается открещивание даже явно тюркских элементов, забывая, что знаменитый Рашид-ад-дин называл русь страной русских и черных клобуков (каракалпаки), что большинство русской элиты носили фамилий с тюркскими корнями. Наши русские братья, вы знаете, что среди казахов есть племя орыс (русские)? У нас больше общего, наши деды умирали бок о бок при защите Москвы. Давайте гордится общей историей и долой этих немецких натравителей.

Answer (score 0):

Богатырь = "бага" + "тыр".
С базы осетинского языка такая формула означает следующее:
"бага" - общеиранское (и общеарийское) понятие "бог";
"тыр"  - отрок, молодой человек.
Таким образом, "богатырь" - это божественный/бога отрок.
Такая характеристика среди прочих подразумевает и наделенность большой силой и волей.

В осетинском языке также имеется это слово, почти так же 
звучащее и с ударением на 2й слог.
В русскую среду это понятие могло попасть от алан и сармат (предков осетин).

Answer (score -1):

Почему вы все так упорно цепляетесь за тюркскую версию ?!  В своём ответе на вопрос "Фамилии русских богатырей" я доходчиво объяснил , что это были *хазарские ландскнехты на службе древнерусских князей* . Слово <<**БОГАТЫРЬ**>> применялось в отношении русских воинов , живших много ранее появления на Руси монголо-татар со своими *батырами* . Давайте откроем   памятник древерусского фольклора , былину **"Как перевелись богатыри на святой Руси"** ./по интернет-ссылке [былина Как переаелись богатыри](https://sites.google.com/site/russkieskazki/home/byliny/kak-perevelis-bogatyri-na-svatoj-rusi)/  В самом начале , в зачине , звучат строки: "*Убирайте-ка вы легки стреженьки* / *Дорогим суконцем багрецовым,* / Увивайте-ка весёльчики Аравитским красным золотом,* / *Увивайте-ка укрюченьки Цареградским крупным жемчугом:* / *Чтобы по ночам они не буркали,* / *Чтоб не подавали ясака* / **Ко тем злым людям - татаровьям** ."  Слова "... **ко тем злым людям - татаровьям**" сразу отмежевывает русских богатырей от татар и *батыров* . Далее повествуется о том , как богатыри встали на Сафат-реке (река Калка ? река Сить ? река Днепр ?) у старого дуба , где сходятся три дороги , - на Киев , на Новгород , и третья к *далекому синему морю* . Батыево нашествие прошло через Киев , не затронуло Новгород и покатилось дальше к Адриатике ("*ко сини морю далёкому*") . Вражеская рать , которую встретили русские богатыри на Сафат-реке, и было тем монголо-татарским нашествием . В нём русские богатыри и погибли и " ...*С тех-то пор могучие богатыри* / *И перевелись на святой Руси!* " . Как видим богатыри это те , кто были защитниками Руси до появления монголо-тюркских *батыров* . Обратим в тексте былины на одну интересную деталь , повторяющуюся неоднократно применительно к разным из собравшихся на Сафат-реке богатырей . Сначала Алёша Попович : "*Разгорался на слове их млад Алешенька,* / *Разгонял коня ретивого,* / *Налетел на супротивников,* / **Разрубает пополам их со всего плеча** ... " . То же самое - Добрыня Никитич : "*Налетел на них Добрынюшка Никитич млад,* / **Разрубает пополам их со всего плеча** ..." . Ну и , наконец Илья Муромец : "*Налетает старый Илья Муромец,* / **Разрубает пополам их со всего плеча** ..." . Вспомним и Евпатия Коловрата из "*Повести о разорении Рязани Батыем* " , - он тоже одним ударом рассёк татарского витязя Хоставрула на две половинки от макушки до седла . Правда , в тексте "*Повести* ..." Евпатий не назван *богатырём* , - он назван *исполином* (дважды) ; но , вероятно , Евпатий и не был *хазаром* по происхождению . Итак , возьмём за исходное предположение , что способность одним ударом рассечь противника надвое , была своего рода тестом на статус богатыря . Такое дело промелькнуло в истории и у арабских воинов с их бохадурами . Ну , теперь попробуем докопаться до истину при помощи ... - вы уже , наверное догадываетесь , -  конечно же , иврита ! Откроем ИРИС-словарь /[Ирис-словарь](http://www.slovar.co.il/translate.php) и экспериментальным путём , имея в виду , что ивритная буква йуд י =**Й**-**И** может в прекладе на другие языки может заменяться/дополняться буквой **Г**(**G**) , увидим там слово **ביתר** , по- буквенно (чтение иврита справа-налево !) бет **ב**  =Б , йуд **י** =Й-И , тав **ת** =Т , реш **ר**  =Р . Вместе (по-буквенно) **БЙТР** . Я уже обращал внимание , что ивритная йуд в перекладе может заменяться/дополняться буквой **Г**(=**G**) (смотрите это в моём ответе о старухе Изергиль) : в итальянском языке все библейские имена, начинающиеся на Йе/Йа/Йо/Йу, пишутся с начальной **G** : Geronimo, Giacomo, Giordano, Giovanni, , Giacobbe, Gisella и др. То есть , там , где в ивритном оригинале стоит йуд , она дополнеется **G** . Могу привести и другие примеры такого рода : *испанский* - *гишпанский* (во времена Петра I-го) , *Иларий* (православное каноническое имя) - *Гиляровский* (фамилия известного писателя) . А переводится это **БЙТР**=**БГТР** , как <<**РАССЕКАТЬ** , **РАСЧЛЕНЯТЬ**>> . //// **Вот вам и этимология слова <<БОГАТЫРЬ>> !** //// Есть и ещё один перевод : <<**С ЕЩЁ БОЛЬШИМ**>> , т.е. один против многих (*например , в русской летописи Рагдай - один против тёхсот*) .   См. скриншот из ИРИС-словаря :                      [image: БЙТР] ===========================================================================                              Я же ещё в ответе про "Фамилии русских богатырей" написал , что это были хазарские ландскнехты на службе Руси . А арабское <<БОХАДУР>> точно также является семитским словом в схожем варианте .