# Этимология слова "богатырь"

Tags: этимология

Первая часть слова "богатырь" понятна всем. А вот вторая. Что за "тырь"?))) Задорнов дает свою трактовку, но я знаю, как тут к нему относятся. Просто никаких других я не слышал. Но интересно было бы узнать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По М. Фасмеру этимология слова "богатЫрь": "укр. богати́р, др.-русск. богатырь (Ипатьевск. и др.), польск. bohater, bohatyr, стар. bohaterz (в грам.). Вторично образовано укр. багати́р, блр. багаты́р "богатей, богач" от бога́тый; см. Брандт, РФВ 21, 210. Заимств. из др.-тюрк. *baɣatur (откуда и венг. bátor "смелый"), дунайско-булг. βαγάτουρ, тур., чагат. batur "смелый, военачальник", шор. paɣattyr "герой", монг. bagatur, калм. bātr̥; см. Гомбоц 41; Рамстедт, KWb. 38; Бернекер 1, 66; Маркварт, Chronol. 40; Банг, KSz 18, 119; Mi. TEl. 1, 254, Доп. 1, 9; 2, 80. Объяснение вост. слов из ир.* baɣapuϑra- (Локоч 15) весьма сомнительно".

На Руси это слово впервые употреблено в Ипатьевской летописи, причём применительно не к русским воинам, а к Себедяю и Бурундаю – военачальникам хана Батыя. 
В домонгольский же период для аналогичного понятия у нас существовало славянское слово «хоробр».

В процессе поиска ответа мне на глаза попалась статья Павла Густерина, научного сотрудника Института востоковедения РАН. Прочитайте его исследовательскую работу. См.http://rusplt.ru/articles/life/life_782.html

Comment: Да уж. Трудно назвать ее исследовательской, скорее реферативной, просто привел разные мнения, даже не определился со своей точкой зрения.

Comment: Мне слово "хоробр" больше нравится!)))

Answer (score 2):

Задорнова - ффтопку.
Остальное - [тут](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/9374/%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%80%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%80)

Answer (score 0):

Это спецназ монголов, цитата-*Кроме того было организовано элитное подразделение из тысячи багатуров — лучших воинов, которые получали это почётное звание за боевые заслуги.*(википедия)

Comment: Но разве это как-то исключает все другие версии? А откуда цитата - и почему её надо принимать на веру? Впрочем, уже хорошо, что вы не сводите (вслед за Задорновым) к "Бога тырь!"